# CSS full height not working in a scroll box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been stuck with this simple problem for a while now. It might be a duplication but I couldn't find a similar problem online.

I am trying to make the green bar height 100% (to have the same height as the red parent).

Here is a codepen if it helps: https://codepen.io/tartie2/pen/NWYZpgj

Here is the code:

```css
div {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

div::after{
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width:10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder why you are using `::after` ? Are you trying to have a thick green left border on the red div?

Comment: No, this is just a simple example. I am trying to make a skeleton loader and I need vertical bar that takes the all height of the parent. And I thought that using ::after was a pretty good choice compared to making a new div element. But I am not too sure how I could achieve that with ::after

Comment: better share you real use case if you want to get accurate answers. This specific case can be solved in different ways but I am pretty sure none will be useful to your real use case.

Comment: that's my use case, I just removed the animation and the styles. I am open to any suggestions and don't mind changing my code. But I thought this could be done with the ::after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.green-bar,
.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.green-bar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="green-bar"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. I have decided to go with the wrapper approach.

Answer (score 1):

The parent has an explicit height of `200px`. The `::after` element is trying to fill that height. If you remove the `height` property from the parent then the pseudo element will fill up the entire height of the parent.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This makes total sense but what if I wanted to keep that red box height of 200px ? Would I be forced to add some kind of wrapper ? I am trying to only use the ::after

Comment: Not exactly. The problem your code was facing was that the `div` was set to `200px` in height, but it was overflowing causing the element to stretch out. If you would add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: scroll`, then the `::after` would be the same height as the `div` as the content won't stretch the element out anymore.